# how to add rel noindex to an div with type="text/javascript"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nofollow, noindex

I want to add rel `noindex` to an div used in my site to display ads.

**This is my code used in the page for dispaly:**

```
@if ($ad = $options->getFooterAd())
 <div id="ad">{{ $ad }}</div>
@endif
```

**This is the code for getFooterAd (watch above)**

```
 <div id="SC_TBlock_12345" class="SC_TBlock">loading...</div>
```

**And down in the same page (at the bottom of the page,I have the script):**

```
<script type="text/javascript">var SC_CId = "12345",SC_Domain="n.ads1-adnow.com";SC_Start_12345=(new Date).getTime();</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://st.n.ads1-adnow.com/js/adv_out.js"></script>
```

Of corse the ideal solution, is to add `noindex` to the div id=ad, but if is not possible, need to find some different solution.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Why do you work with Adnow man?   They are a scam business, you will reach your $20 minimum payment and then they won't pay you anyways.